# No additional postbacks work if validation fails on first postback

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, validation, webforms

I have never noticed that ASP.NET automatically shuts down all subsequent postbacks until the field that validated as false is fixed by the user.

**My scenario:**
I have a form with 3 fields. One of them is a Textbox (txtCarName) with a required field validator and then I have a dropdown(ddlCarMake) with AutoPostBack=true, that filters and enables another dropdown (ddlCarModel) OnSelectedIndexChange.

Lets say the user clicks the save button without filling out the required textbox (txtCarName). They will be notifed that it is a required field. 
Before they go and add a value to the required textbox lets say they decide to edit the ddlCarMake because they change their mind. In this case the filter does not happen since all subsequent postbacks are disabled. The user would be extremely confused.

How do ASP.NET developers avoid something like this from creating a poor user experience?

**UPDATE:**

After contacting Telerik they told me this is a known issue and is currently fixed in their internal build. The next release it will be fixed.

Comment: You want to be using [Validation groups](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424%28v=vs.140%29.aspx) to group the related fields together.

Comment: I am in a Wizard control. I have a few controls in Step1 as described above (all in validationgroup 'Step1'. When they click next, the next button ValidationGroup is set to 'Step1'. I am not sure how setting the validation group would change the situation here. With or without validation groups I think this is how ASP.NET validation and postbacks act.

Comment: You also need to post some code.

Comment: This is my mistake. After doing testing on a testpage without using the wizard control I am using everything works as normal. For some reason on Next button click which is where the validation group is set, it is displaying the validation summary like it is supposed to, but shuts down all subsequent potbacks... I will have to take this one up with telerik

Answer (score -2):

set the dropdownlist CausesValidation="False"

Comment: Sorry, that isn't the problem. Something weird is happening only within the RadWizard control when the next button is clicked. The next button is a RadButton so maybe it is doing something strange.

Comment: so when you added the RadWizard again and set the CausesValidation on the dropdownlist to false, that didn't solve your issue?

Comment: No I tried it and it didn't work. I set both dropdowns that are involved to CausesValidation=false.